# load() in joomla to add part of form returns 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, joomla3.0

I am trying to use jQuery - AJAX load() Method to load part of registration form as a primitive protection against spam. I do not have experience with ajax and jquery in joomla and I suspect that is main problem here.

I tried to modify existing default.php file of registration form with code from https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_load.asp. It does someting, but not what I want it to.
Insted of loading separate file content that I set, it shows whole webpage in selected DIV with 404 error.
Here is example in action:
https://ambicij.si/2019/index.php/davki/seminar-davki-v-podjetjih-in-poudarek-na-dohodnini-obdavcitev-razlicnih-izplacil-zdoh-2/individual-registration

If you press "External Content" button it will show what I described. I would like to move submit buttons from DIV gumbi to external file so visitor will have to load buttons prior submiting form.
Below is code I put into default.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("button").click(function(){
          jQuery("#gumbi").load("test.html", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
           if(statusTxt == "success")
               alert("External content loaded successfully!");
           if(statusTxt == "error")
               alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
          });
        });
       });
</script> 
 <button>Get External Content</button>
    <div id="gumbi" class="form-actions">
        <input type="button" class="<?php echo $btnPrimary; ?>" name="btnBack" value="<?php echo  JText::_('EB_BACK') ;?>" onclick="window.history.go(-1);" />
        <input type="submit" class="<?php echo $btnPrimary; ?>" name="btn-submit" id="btn-submit" value="<?php echo $buttonText;?>" />
        <img id="ajax-loading-animation" src="<?php echo JUri::base(true);?>/media/com_eventbooking/ajax-loadding-animation.gif" style="display: none;"/>

    </div>
```

and here is external test.html:

```
  <html>
    <p>test</p>
  </html>
```

As mentioned already, I would like to load code from test.html into div gumbi, but currently I get whole web page with 404 error. Since problem is not resolved, you can see it by following my link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ajax request to "test.html" resolves to this url:

https://ambicij.si/2019/index.php/davki/seminar-davki-v-podjetjih-in-poudarek-na-dohodnini-obdavcitev-razlicnih-izplacil-zdoh-2/test.html

however your index.php is not able to find or load test.html and responds with Http 302 redirect going to error page. 302 Redirect is not http error so your ajax call treats it as success, error handler never fires and content of error page is loaded into your div.

Perhaps test.html was not uploaded  or you might want to check code inside index.php to make sure it can find the file.

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. It was my belief that file was found since script did not report error. Thank you for explanation about this.